# how to extract MAX value with multiple conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, max

I'm dumping an SQL sales/order table and running the following Excel array command to find the highest value, for a particular order:

{ =MAX(IF([ORDER]=[@[ORDER]];IF([PRODUCT]=[@PRODUCT];[QTY]))) }

This checks, for any rows belonging to the same order, for the same product, what the highest QTY listed is. But being an Arry formula, it freezes my Excel for many minutes.

Can I do something similar directly in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can get `MAX` value with `aggregate function` `MAX` and apply condition with `WHERE` like below.

```
SELECT MAX(QTY)
FROM TABLE
WHERE [ORDER] = @ORDER AND [PRODUCT] = @PRODUCT
```

And if you want `ORDER` and `PRODUCT` wise `MAX` `QTY` value for all `ORDER` and `PRODUCT` then use `GROUP BY` like below.

```
SELECT MAX(QTY)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY [ORDER], [PRODUCT]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value per row, then you would use window functions:

```
select t.*, max(qty) over (partition by order, product)
from t;
```

Note:  `order` is a very bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.  If that is the real name, you need to escape it.